# Blockchain.info receive payments API, bitcoins lost?

Tags: blockchain.info, unconfirmed-transactions, lost-bitcoins

I use the Blockchain.info receive payments API. It's all working nice and good, but now I have a payment that doesn't reach my adress. It is unconfirmed for almost 24 hours.

Also, the payment doesn't show in Bitcoin-QT (also not as unconfirmed)

You can see here: https://blockchain.info/address/1J2SpT8wBUsVhP6MBtc5sqJkUMgdfHPSZ4

Normally Blockchain.info pays the miner fee, so I should receive them very quickly.

Are my bitcoins lost in the abyss?

Answer (score 0):

Seems the payment got through after all. Weird, it took more than 24 hours.

So, just wait and keep waiting, in the end, it's all gonna be alright.

Comment: In any case, if any payment is unconfirmed for any reason (including being added to a block that gets reorganized away), the bitcoins are not lost: they are still in the sending wallet (though a rescan may be needed if the wallet doesn't realize). Only a valid tx included in the blockchain can move bitcoins from one address to another.